# Adding row values then dividing between data frames

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, divide

The first data frame I have looks like this:

```
ID 2016 2017
1  5    6
2  15   20
3  10   10
```

The second data frame is identical, but with different values:

```
ID 2016 2017
1  20   30
2  50   40
3  10   15
```

I'd like to add ID numbers 1 and 3 in each table, then divide the first data frame by the second in a new data frame. I'd also like to divide ID 2 in the first table by ID 2 in the second. Finally, I'd like the new data frame to have row names with the results of these calculations, so:

```
Type 2016 2017
A    0.5  0.36
B    0.3  0.5
```

Row A would be the result of ID 1 and 3, while Row B is the result of ID 2.

Comment: Interesting -- what have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  this, we can also use `base R`.  Get the `colSums` of subset of rows of both datasets, divide, `rbind` with the division of 2nd rows of each dataset

```
cbind(Type = c('A', 'B'), rbind.data.frame(colSums(df1[-2, 
     -1])/colSums(df2[-2, -1]), df1[2, -1]/df2[2, -1]))
#   Type 2016      2017
#1    A  0.5 0.3555556
#2    B  0.3 0.5000000
```

Here, the subsetting is done for rows and columns with index

```
df2[-2, -1]
```

implies, we remove the 2nd rows and the first column.  The indexing is row,column.  If it is positive, then we are keeping that rows/columns.  Here, those rows/columns are removed.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, `2016` = c(5L, 15L, 10L), `2017` = c(6L, 
20L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, X2016 = c(20L, 50L, 10L), X2017 = c(30L, 
40L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the -2, -1 and 2, -1 part of your solution?

Comment: @AliceWang yes, it is the indexing to remove the row/column.  With negative, it is removing that particular row/column.  I updated the post

Comment: This worked. However, I'm trying to output the results using write_xlsx. It's not giving me an error, but it's also not outputting the file. Do you know why this could be>

Comment: @AliceWang From the example posted, it is a regular data.frame.  Can you check the `str(output)`

Comment: The output for 2016 and 2017 are both num. The output for Type was factor. I tried changing from factor to character, but it still didn't output.

Comment: It seems that the error was because I was trying to have a / in the output file name. Getting rid of the / fixed the issue. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AliceWang Always check `str` first after you read and before you write.  It can save a lot of time thinking about the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

df1 <- structure(list(`2016` = c(5L, 15L, 10L), `2017` = c(6L, 20L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(`2016` =  c(20L, 50L, 10L), `2017` = c(30L, 40L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# add ID to each dataframe

df1  %>%  
  rowid_to_column(var = "ID")
#>   ID 2016 2017
#> 1  1    5    6
#> 2  2   15   20
#> 3  3   10   10
```

To create a third dataframe based on your requirements, I'm not sure we need the ID column so...

```
#A little function to prepare each data frame

df_Type <- function(x){

  x %>% 
  mutate(Type = c("A", "B", "A")) %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)

}


# the function could be place in the list below to avoid additional objects but it makes it clear what is happening

df1_Type <- df_Type(df1)

df2_Type <- df_Type(df2)

> df2_Type
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Type  `2016` `2017`
  <chr>  <int>  <int>
1 A         30     45
2 B         50     40

#dividing one data frame by the other

list(select_if(df1_Type, is.numeric),
     select_if(df2_Type, is.numeric)) %>% 
pmap_dfr(function(x, y) x / y) %>% 
bind_cols(df1_Type[, 1]) %>% 
  select(Type, everything())

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   Type  `2016` `2017`
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 A        0.5  0.356
#> 2 B        0.3  0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>